# Looking for the name of particular collection of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

I came across the following algebraic structure when working on a seemingly unrelated problem and am unable to find a name for it.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity.  Given indeterminates $x^{\alpha}_{i},$ where $1 \leq \alpha \leq m,$ $1 \leq i \leq n,$  (Note: $\alpha$ is superscript, not an exponent), consider the $R$-module $W_q$ of of defined by,
$$
W_q =\left\{ \sum_{p \leq q} S^{\, i_1 \, i_2 \,  \dots   i_p}_{\alpha_1\alpha_2 \dots \alpha_p} \, x^{\alpha_1}_{i_1} x^{\alpha_2}_{i_1}  \dots x^{\alpha_p}_{i_p}  \ \  |  \    \  S^{\, i_1 \, i_2 \,  \dots   i_p}_{\alpha_1\alpha_2 \dots \alpha_p} \in R , \ \text{skew-symm. in lower and upper indices}  \right\}, 
$$
where the Einstein summation convention is in effect here.

Clearly $W_0=R$, $W_1=\{ a + b^i_\alpha x^\alpha_i \ : \ a,b^i_\alpha \in R\}$ and $W_{r}=W_{\max\{m,n\}}$ whenever $r \geq \max\{m,n\}.$

Also, $W_q$ is an $R$-submodule of $R[x^1_1,x^1_2,\dots,x^1_n,x^2_1,x^2_2,\dots, x_{m}^n].$  Moreover, $W_q$ is a submodule of the of the symmetric polynomials.

My specific question is this:  Is there a generally accepted name for the set $W_q$, or least an $R$-module isomorphism between $W_q$ and some well recognized structure?

Comment: Why would $W_0$ and $W_1$ be $0$? Your notation looks like $W_0$ would be $R$ itself (the sum of terms $S$ with $p=0$), and $W_1$ would be the space of all polynomials of degree at most $1$. The antisymmetry would only come into play for $q\ge 2$; before that there are no nontrivial permutations of a set of indices anyway.

Comment: It also looks like $W_q$ would be a free module, certainly a "well recognized structure",

Comment: @HenningMakholm.  You are right.  I was quotienting out the linear terms in the problem I was working on and got sloppy on the post.